# Find equation of axis of given parabola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

$(ax+by)^2 +2fy = 0$

We are given that this equation represents a curve with a,b,f belonging to real number not equal to zero. We are then asked to prove that the curve represents a parabola and to find its axis. I can prove that the curve is a parabola because the second degree terms form a perfect square and the discriminant is non zero but I am not sure how to proceed with finding the axis of the parabola. I tried comparing this equation with the general equation but that led to nowhere and was too lengthy. Can anyone suggest a method to proceed with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that$$y=\frac{b(ax+by)+a(-bx+ay)}{a^2+b^2}$$and that therefore\begin{multline}(ax+by)^2+2fy=0\iff(ax+by)^2+\frac{2fb(ax+by)}{a^2+b^2}+\frac{2fa(-bx+ay)}{a^2+b^2}=0\\\iff\left((ax+by)+\frac{bf}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2-\frac{b^2f^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2}+2\frac{fa}{a^2+b^2}(-bx+ay)=0.\end{multline}If $X=ax+by$ and $Y=-bx+ay$, this is simply$$\left(X+\frac{bf}{a^2+b^2}\right)^2-\frac{b^2f^2}{(a^2+b^2)^2}+2\frac{fa}{a^2+b^2}Y=0.$$The axis of symmetry of this parabola is the line $X=-\frac{bf}{a^2+b^2}$. So, the axis of symmetry of your parabola is$$ax+by=-\frac{bf}{a^2+b^2}.$$